# Как представить python-словарь в виде таблицы

Tags: python, python-3.x, словари

Столкнулся с необходимостью представить python словарь (dictionary) в какую-либо таблицу(может быть в базу данных, или еще как). подскажите, как лучше это осуществить? И, может быть данные лучше хранить данные не в  словаре, а в Series?

```
import pandas as pd
import pymysql
import numpy as np


db = pymysql.connect(host='localhost', user='root', passwd='',
                  database='mom_db', charset='utf8')
df = pd.read_sql("SELECT * FROM comments ", db)
cursor = db.cursor()

name = df['nickname']

count = pd.value_counts(name)

a = {count.index[i]:count[i] for i in range(len(count))}
print(a)
#print(count[count>1])-вывод Series
```

**выводит:**

```
{'repeinik': 26, 'podberezowik': 24, 'Павел_Шуков_talks48': 20, 'stupich': 
14, 'kipovets': 14, 'Лайош_Портиш': 13, 'vijigau_mraz': 13, 'наивная баба': 
12, 'genek77': 12, 'Sergey_Petrov': 12, 'Андрей_Иванов_talks19': 11, 
'Пачотны тунеядзец': 10, 'eugenenus_': 10, 'Настя_Романова': 9, 'Kac_Lol': 
9, 'Ириша_Лалапусечка': 9, 'valstar78': 8, 'Сергей Александрович': 8, 
'Tadeush_Тадеуш': 8, 'freedom for us': 7, 'Светлана_Малышкина': 7, 
'Костя_Миронов': 7, 'SIgarA': 6, 'Жанна_Д-урк': 6, 'Fair play': 6, 
'Лукашенко_Федор': 6, 'Lisa_Grodno': 5, 'id350886439': 5,......
```

**и если выводить Series:**

```
repeinik                  26
podberezowik              24
Павел_Шуков_talks48       20
stupich                   14
kipovets                  14
Лайош_Портиш              13
.......
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
print('{:<20} {:<15}'.format('NickName', 'Numb_comm'))
for name, n_comm in a.items():
   print('{:<20} {:<15}'.format(name, n_comm))
```

**результат**

```
NickName             Numb_comm      
repeinik             26             
podberezowik         24             
Павел_Шуков_talks48  20             
stupich              14             
kipovets             14             
Лайош_Портиш         13             
vijigau_mraz         13             
наивная баба         12             
genek77              12
```

Answer (score 6):

Мне вот у модуля [tabulate](https://github.com/gregbanks/python-tabulate) нравятся таблицы (а через параметр `tablefmt` можно [разные стили](https://github.com/gregbanks/python-tabulate#table-format) задавать):

```
# pip install tabulate
from tabulate import tabulate

d = {'repeinik': 26, 'podberezowik': 24, 'Павел_Шуков_talks48': 20, 
     'stupich': 14, 'kipovets': 14, 'Лайош_Портиш': 13, 
     'vijigau_mraz': 13, 'наивная баба': 12, 'genek77': 12}
print(tabulate(d.items(), headers=['NAME', 'VALUE'], tablefmt="grid"))
```

Консоль:

```
+---------------------+---------+
| NAME                |   VALUE |
+=====================+=========+
| repeinik            |      26 |
+---------------------+---------+
| podberezowik        |      24 |
+---------------------+---------+
| Павел_Шуков_talks48 |      20 |
+---------------------+---------+
| stupich             |      14 |
+---------------------+---------+
| kipovets            |      14 |
+---------------------+---------+
| Лайош_Портиш        |      13 |
+---------------------+---------+
| vijigau_mraz        |      13 |
+---------------------+---------+
| наивная баба        |      12 |
+---------------------+---------+
| genek77             |      12 |
+---------------------+---------+
```

Comment: что-то Anaconda prompt не пожелала ставить этот модуль

Comment: а что в консоли пишет?

Comment: (base) c:\ospanel>conda install tabulate


Solving environment: failed

UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be in conflict:
  - tabulate
  - zict
Use "conda info <package>" to see the dependencies for each package.

Comment: а вот просто в python установилось...)

Answer (score 3):

```
d = {'repeinik': 26, 'podberezowik': 24, 'Павел_Шуков_talks48': 20, 'stupich': 14, 'kipovets': 14, 'Лайош_Портиш': 13, 'vijigau_mraz': 13, 'наивная баба': 12, 'genek77': 12}

print("{:<20} {:<15}".format('Name','Value'))
for v in d.items():
    name, val = v
    print("{:<20} {:<15}".format(name, val))
```

**Результат**

```
Name                    Value
repeinik                26    
podberezowik            24
Павел_Шуков_talks48     20
...                     ...
```

Похожий вопрос на SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17330139/python-printing-a-dictionary-as-a-horizontal-table-with-headers

Comment: Спасибо. Вот только выдает: 
    File "<ipython-input-200-baa21420482e>", line 20
    print "{:<20} {:<15}".format('Name','Value')
                        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: @lynx немного опечатался. Исправил ответ и переделал его под python 3.

Answer (score 1):

В вашем случае будет выгоднее сделать группировку на стороне MySQL сервера, чтобы не тащить все данные с сервера:

```
select name, cnt from (
  select name, count(*) as cnt from tab group by name order by cnt desc
) as v limit 3;
```

[Тест на SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f34940/5)

и потом просто прочитать результат данного SQL в DataFrame

---

Если делать это средствами Pandas:

Тестовый набор случайных данных с неравномерным распределением:

```
In [63]: df = pd.DataFrame({
    ...:                  'name':np.random.choice(['aaa','bbb','ccc', 'ddd', 'eee', 'fff'], 100, p=[0.4, .13, .15, .05, .2, .07])
    ...:               })
    ...:
    ...:
```

PS тот же набор данных я использовал для SQLFiddle...

Выбираем top 3:

```
In [69]: df['name'].value_counts().iloc[:3].reset_index(name='cnt').rename(columns={'index':'name'})
Out[69]:
  name  cnt
0  aaa   45
1  eee   19
2  ccc   13
```

Comment: что-то я не разобрался с предложенным вами решением
  df = pd.DataFrame({
                 'name':np.random.choice(['aaa','bbb','ccc'], 500, p=[0.55, .3, .15])
              })

вот это для чего?

Comment: @lynx, это для создания исходного DataFrame, на котором можно было показать как это работает... В вашем случае это был бы ‘df’, который вы получили из БД

Comment: Да, заработало, но все же выводит не совсем так, как мне нужно.
Выводит просто набор никнеймов и кол-во их встреч, вне зависимости от этого кол-ва. А мне же нужно именно ранжированно, первые 20