# таблица из словаря словарей без pandas на python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
{1: {'1_home_page': 22600, '2_search_page': 13554, '3_payment_page': 2390, '4_payment_confirmation_page': 189}, 2: {'1_home_page': 22600, '2_search_page': 13687, '3_payment_page': 2412, '4_payment_confirmation_page': 173}, 3: {'1_home_page': 22600, '2_search_page': 8879, '3_payment_page': 631, '4_payment_confirmation_page': 44}, 4: {'1_home_page': 22600, '2_search_page': 9080, '3_payment_page': 597, '4_payment_confirmation_page': 46}}
```

как из этого словаря сделать таблицу на печати  типа

1_home_page   22600 22600 22600 22600
2_search_page 13554 13687 8879 9080

Comment: вот тут посмотрите 
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/788866/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-python-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8C-%D0%B2-%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B5-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8B

Answer (score 1):

Например, так:

```
from collections import defaultdict

dict_of_dict = {1: {'1_home_page': 22600, '2_search_page': 13554, '3_payment_page': 2390, '4_payment_confirmation_page': 189}, 2: {'1_home_page': 22600, '2_search_page': 13687, '3_payment_page': 2412, '4_payment_confirmation_page': 173}, 3: {'1_home_page': 22600, '2_search_page': 8879, '3_payment_page': 631, '4_payment_confirmation_page': 44}, 4: {'1_home_page': 22600, '2_search_page': 9080, '3_payment_page': 597, '4_payment_confirmation_page': 46}}

new_dict = defaultdict(list)
for d in dict_of_dict.values():
    for k,v in d.items():
        new_dict[k].append(v)

for k,v in new_dict.items():
    print(k, *v, end=' ')
```

Вывод:

```
1_home_page 22600 22600 22600 22600 2_search_page 13554 13687 8879 9080 3_payment_page 2390 2412 631 597 4_payment_confirmation_page 189 173 44 46
```